# Hotwire/Turbo Frames: why `target: "_top"` isn't requesting pages via fetch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, hotwire

I'm in the early stages of migrating a Rails app from Turbolinks/rails-ujs (using good ol `js.erb` views that worked wonders) to Hotwire/Turbo.

Picture a traditional `users/index.html.erb` page with a search form and results table:

```rb
<%= form_with(scope: :search, url: url_for, method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: "users_table" }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.search_field :name %>

<% end %>

<%= turbo_frame_tag("users_table") do %>
  
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= link_to user.name, user, target: :_top %>
  <% end %>

  <%== pagy_bootstrap_nav(@pagy) %>

<% end %>
```

So, the search form above can update the turbo_frame_tag below without a full page reload (which keeps the focus and the state in the form, as desired).

Each link inside the turbo_frame_tag is expected to navigate to /users/show, replacing the entire page. And it works, due to the inclusion of the `target: :_top` attribute in each link.

However, the user experience is suffering. With Turbolinks, each link inside the users_table issued a AJAX navigation, replaching the 'body' and felt very, very snappy. With Turbo/Hotwire, I can see in devtools that only the pagination (inside the turbo frame) and form submission (due to the turbo_frame attribute) are being fetched using `fetch`, while the link in the user name is being requested as a regular `document` navigation.

It gets worse: the back button also doesn't have any cache, so clicking in an user name and coming back takes 5 times more than it took with Turbolinks.

Is this an expected regression when using Turbo? Anytime I have a link inside a turbo_frame that I want to break out of the frame I'm losing all the benefits of the ajax navigation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution.

Instead of

```rb
<%= link_to user.name, user, target: :_top %>
```

One should use

```rb
<%= link_to user.name, user, data: { turbo_frame: :_top } %>
```

Comment: if you wondering why turbo reloading the full page instead just swapping the body, this is the solution too, this is the correct syntax as per [turbo doc](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames#targeting-navigation-into-or-out-of-a-frame)